# Setting table expiration time using Dataflow BigQuery sink

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-dataflow

Is there way to set the [expiration](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/tables) time on a BigQuery table when using Dataflow's `BigQueryIO.Write` sink?

For example, I'd like something like this (see last line):

```
PCollection<TableRow> mainResults...
mainResults.apply(BigQueryIO.Write
                .named("my-bq-table")
                .to("PROJECT:dataset.table")
                .withSchema(getBigQueryTableSchema())
                .withWriteDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.WriteDisposition.WRITE_TRUNCATE)
                .withCreateDisposition(BigQueryIO.Write.CreateDisposition.CREATE_IF_NEEDED))
                .withExpiration(1452030098l) //**this table should expire on 31st Jan
```

I can't see anything in the Dataflow API that would facilitate this. Of course, I could just use the BigQuery API, but it would be much better to be able to this in the via Dataflow when specifying the sink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't currently supported in the Dataflow API.  We can look at adding it soon, as it should be a straightforward addition.

Comment: Is the feature request page like there is for BigQuery? e.g. https://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery/

Comment: We monitor the Github issue tracker for the SDK, at https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/DataflowJavaSDK/issues

Comment: Do you want me to raise it there?

Comment: Done. Thanks Sam :-)

Comment: Please follow [BEAM-50](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-50) for further updates on this.

Answer (score 0):

You can set a `defaultTableExpirationMs` on a dataset, and then any table created within that dataset will have an Expiration Time of "now + dataset.defaultTableExpirationMs".

See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/v2/datasets#defaultTableExpirationMs

Comment: Yeah, but that's not possible via the Dataflow API unfortunately.